# How to obtain explicit formula of coefficients for generating functions?

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, python, sagemath

Is there any function in python or sage to obtain explicit formula of coefficients for generating functions.
For example, Catalan generating function is given as

$${\displaystyle c(x)={\dfrac {1-{\sqrt {1-4x}}}{2x}}}$$
And I need to obtain general formula for $n$th coefficient:

$${\displaystyle C_{n}={\dfrac {1}{2n+1}}{2n+1 \choose n}}$$

Comment: There are many tricks involving known series, differentiation and integration, as well as other manipulations, but there's no *silver bullet* to my knowledge. In the case of the Catalan numbers, you can use Newton's binomial expansion and some algebraic manipulations of factorials.

Comment: There are packages like [rec_sequences](https://github.com/PhilippNuspl/rec_sequences) that could be used to fund a recurrence to solve. Another way is to generate the data and look in OEIS; ex: `[( (1-sqrt(1-4*x^2))/(2*x) ).series(x,n+1).list()[n] for n in (0..30)]` leads to sequence [A126120](https://oeis.org/A126120). Otherwise its better to start with paper and pen and get the work done before heading to codes.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want the
generalized binomial theorem
which is

$(1+x)^a
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{a}{n}x^n
$
where
$\binom{a}{n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-k)}{n!}
$.

For your case
$a=\dfrac12$
so,
for $n \ge 1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{\frac12}{n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac12-k)}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\frac12(1-2k))}{n!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^n\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(2k-1)}{2^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k-1)}{2^nn!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k)}{2^nn!\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(2k)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}\prod_{k=1}^{2n-2}k}{2^nn!2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n-2)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt {1-4x}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac12}{n}(-4x)^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n-2)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n-1)!}(-1)^n4^nx^n\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}x^n\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac {1-\sqrt {1-4x}}{2x}
&=\dfrac{2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}x^n}{2x}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}x^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n+1)!}{(2n+1)n!(n+1)!}x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n}x^{n}\\
\end{array}
$

I'll be glad to explain
any of this you do not understand
since it uses
a number of
standard manipulations
you should get
familiar with.